# Transfer file over socket

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer

I found this [code](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/blog/2004/november/15.html) witch I tried and it works great but(!). I want to store the file in a folder that I will choose and also get it from a folder that I again will chose. Since the Sender get an argument then I suppose that if I give an argument like /home/user/test.txt then that's ok and it'll work out fine but I don't get how to store the file to a specific folder ( the Server part in other words ). Any ideas?

If I'm wrong about the argument please by all means correct me :D

PS: It works just fine for the Netbeans' default folder ( no specification of folder for the Sender or Server ).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frankly speaking, though i feel bad about doing your homework, I am just in a good mood :)

In the below code(FileReciever) i have added a new variable folder which is initalized from the first argument passed to main(). So the name of the folder you want to save the file in mus tbe passed as the first argument. The only other line I have changed is:
File file=new File(folder, file_name);

```
private String folder = "";
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
  folder = args[0];
  ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);

  while (true) {
    FileReceiver file_rec = new FileReceiver();
    file_rec.socket = listener.accept();  

    new Thread(file_rec).start();
  }
}
catch (java.lang.Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

}

```
public void run() {
    try {
      InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();


  int nof_files = ByteStream.toInt(in);

  for (int cur_file=0;cur_file < nof_files; cur_file++) {
    String file_name = ByteStream.toString(in);

    File file=new File(folder, file_name);

    ByteStream.toFile(in, file);
  }
}
catch (java.lang.Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much. Well the think is that it is for a homework but is a really small part of it and I asked because in the past I've always had problems with folder paths so I expectes somethings like 
ByteStren.toFile(folfer+file); but you know... one that it'll work. Didn't know the documentation for the java.io.file. 

Another question. It seems that the sender doesn't send from any folder but only the default. Do you know why?

I give as an argument /home/user/test.txt and there's no error but still doesn't work.
Any ideas? I appreciate it and thank you.